# How to set height of element to match height of another element? in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I Want Changing element Size With Visible And Gone Other Element ?
For Example

```html
     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/number1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp" /> 

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/number2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I Want changing this Parameters

> set weight number2 **Equal** with height number1 **For Ever**

Why For Ever ?
**Because by changing the number1 height, the number two changes automatically
**

How Can I Do It ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve the desired behavior.

**The first one**, that requires zero Java/Kotlin code is to use ConstraintLayout as the parent Layout. Just put top/bottom constraints of view2 to match the top/bottom of view1. Keep in mind, this would work only in one case: If your views are horizontally aligned. And to change the visibility of two views simultaneously in that case you would probably have to use [Groups](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Group)

Use this code snipped for a reference:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="[your_constraint]"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="[your_constraint]"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="[your_constraint]"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="[your_constraint]"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="[your_constraint]"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="[your_constraint]"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view_1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_1"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The second one** is to use [View.OnLayoutChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener) from the code. Set it to the first view and programmatically change the height of the second view based on the height of the first one.

Like that in Kotlin:

```
view1.addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, top, _, bottom, _, _, _, _ ->
    view2.layoutParams.height = bottom - top
    view2.requestLayout()
}
```